# css text align center in list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to align the ul in the center, but the label should start at the same point. But i cant get it aligned.

```
<div class="box">
    <ul class="feature-list">
        <li><i class="fa fa-users"></i><label> A Label</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i><label> A Label test</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><label> A Labellongword</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i><label> A Labelsometext</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><label> A tex</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-car"></i><label> A text</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Some simple css

```
.feature-list {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
.box{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLu22cxr/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/wLu22cxr/3/

Changes I made:

```
.feature-list {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.box{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know (or want to set) the width of the list, change it to display:inline-block, then use text-align to position it:

```
.feature-list {
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-size: 14px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
.box {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wLu22cxr/4/)**

Comment: the simplest and best solution

Comment: "...but the label should start at the same point" - they don't.

Comment: @F.Müller - Giving the icons a width is an easy fix for that. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4j94xont/

Comment: I know. But its not always what you want though. Its ok unless you have multiple lines for example. And it should stand there in the solution at least as a note and as it is part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wLu22cxr/2/)

Just add this css rule:

```
.box li{
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

You have to specify width to the `li` elements and set them to center with `margin: 0 auto`. And just aling them to left to get the icon and label right

Comment: Your answer makes it hard to have a variable width though, hold on.

Comment: I know it's not the most elegant solution, but it's easiest and simplest and in most cases your li elements will be the same width

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but you don't want to have to change your CSS when adding a new (long) li element though!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there this should do the trick:

```css
.feature-list {
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 font-size: 14px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.feature-list > li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.fa {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="box">
    <ul class="feature-list">
         <li><i class="fa fa-users"></i><label> A Label</label></li>
         <li><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i><label> A Label test</label></li>
         <li><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><label> A Labellongword</label></li>
         <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i><label> A Labelsometext</label></li>
         <li><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><label> A tex</label></li>
         <li><i class="fa fa-car"></i><label> A text</label></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Note how the items align in 1 line (they start at the same origin). Its unlike the other solutions. There is also the opportunity to set a fixed width for the `.fa` class. This will also work for longer labels - where you have the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this gonna help you. 
  Here is  fiddle Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/ve3ebaaz/2/

```
HTML
<div class="box">
    <ul class="feature-list">
        <li><i class="fa fa-users"></i><label> A Label</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i><label> A Label test</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><label> A Labellongword</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i><label> A Labelsometext</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><label> A tex</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-car"></i><label> A text</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>


----------
css


.feature-list {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-size: 14px;
    width:200px;
    }
.box{
    text-align: justify;
}
```